# Server port doesn't responds to the client data which I pass through other application using netty

Tags: java, sockets, jboss, netty

I'm trying to pass the value to the GPS tracking software which listens for `admprotocol` on port `5092`. When I send a data to the server it doesn't responds. I have ***3 questions***.

- I'm not  there is something wrong with the handler which i'm using.
- should we have to *addLast* ***decoder and encoders*** while initialising the channel as I'm already sending raw data through the console
- I'm creating only Client application which sends this raw data to the mentioned & specific port

  ```
  "010042033836313331313030323639343838320501000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000073"
  ```

Here is the default Juit test code which was already provided in the application and this is the data which I've to send to the particular port.

```
public class AdmProtocolDecoderTest extends ProtocolTest {

@Test
public void testDecode() throws Exception {

    AdmProtocolDecoder decoder = new AdmProtocolDecoder(new AdmProtocol()); 

    ChannelBuffer buf = (ChannelBuffer) binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
            "010042033836313331313030323639343838320501000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000073");

    buf.readUnsignedShort(); // device id
    buf.readUnsignedByte(); // length

    verifyNull(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
            "010042033836313331313030323639343838320501000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000073"));

    verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
            "01002680336510002062A34C423DCF8E42A50B1700005801140767E30F568F2534107D220000"));

    verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
            "010022003300072020000000000000000044062A330000000000107F10565D4A8310"));

    verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
            "0100268033641080207AA34C424CCF8E4239030800005B01140755E30F560000F00F70220000"));

    verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
            "01002680336510002062A34C423DCF8E42A50B1700005801140767E30F568F2534107D220000"));

    verifyPosition(decoder, binary(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
            "01002200333508202000000000000000007F0D9F030000000000E39A1056E24A8210"));
}
    }
```

Here's the code for `verifyNull`

```
protected void verifyNull(BaseProtocolDecoder decoder, Object object) throws Exception {
      Assert.assertNull(decoder.decode(null, null, object));
}
```

Here's the code for `ChannelBuffer`

```
protected ChannelBuffer binary(ByteOrder endianness, String... data) {
    return ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(endianness, 
            DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(concatenateStrings(data)));
}
```

Here is myclient application which sends the data:

```
public class AdmProtocolDecoderTesterOne {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      new AdmProtocolDecoderTesterOne("localhost", 5092).run();
   }

   private final String host;
   private final int port;

   public AdmProtocolDecoderTesterOne(String host, int port) {
      this.host = host;
      this.port = port;
   }

   public void run() throws Exception {
      EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

      try {
         Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap();

         clientBootstrap.group(group);
         clientBootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
         clientBootstrap.handler(new ChannelInit());
         Channel channel = (Channel) clientBootstrap.connect(host, port).sync().channel();
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

         while (true) {
            System.out.println("while");
            channel.writeAndFlush(in.readLine() + "\r\n");
         }
      } finally {
         System.out.println("finally");
         group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
      }
   }
}
```

ChannelInit.java

```
public class ChannelInit  extends  ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{


    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel arg0) throws Exception {

        ChannelPipeline pipeline = arg0.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("frame", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new ClientHandler());
    }
```

ClientHandler.java which extends `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf>`

```
@Override
    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
```